# Finding inverse of a signal using analog circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

How do I use an op amp to find inverse of a voltage signal? In other words, my output signal has an amplitude inverse of amplitude of input signal.

My solution was to convert the signal to digital form, find inverse digitally and then convert back to analog form.

Is there another solution using just analog techniques?

Comment: Can you give an example of exactly what you mean by "inverse of a voltage signal" ?

Comment: If you mean 1/x when you say inverse, see my answer [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141121/is-analog-signal-arithmetic-faster-than-digital-one/141124#141124)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is constrained to be > 0 you can use a simple log-antilog circuit which would likely cost a lot less than a purpose-built multiplier chip. For example, this one in an older [TI app note](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/snoa641b/snoa641b.pdf).

[image]

For the transistors you can use matched duals which cost less than 20 cents each, and the amplifier could be a quad op-amp.

In this case E2 would be your input voltage. and E1 and E3 can be connected to a reference voltage.

Comment: Love this circuit. Learned about it a few months back. The transistors should be matched for accuracy because this circuit really uses "diode" currents, and its important to have Is and Vt matched because matched transistors can  cancel out terms.

Answer (score 0):

TI THS413x simplified schematic, uses an H-Bridge driver driven from a current mirror.
reverse engineered an older differential output amp, subtracting the compensator and adding lower current mirror biasing as per another French design.

[image: TDA7052 rework from TI THS413x]

Comment: Please provide a link or citation for the image you copied into your answer. The policy for this site is that copied material must give credit to the original creator.